# Can someone identify this microprocessor?

Tags: identification, microprocessor

[image]

Can someone identify this microprocessor? I need to reprogram it.

It's from a Ford TCU module.  Something goes wrong during update and I am trying to wake this thing up.

Module was made by Continental.

Comment: A little more info would be helpful

Comment: Like; what equipment it is in and also why you want to reprogram it?

Comment: Seems automotive to me - will be locked anyways

Comment: Its Teleamtics control module from car   something Goes wrong during  update and I would like to reprogram  on the bench

Comment: Is it made by Bosch, Delphi or similar? Many of them feature a DFU mode to flash them against some hard-coded bootloader.

Comment: Module is made by Continental

Comment: You wont have a chance to update it without using some Continental software. Many working hours are put into security in automotive electronics. I doubt they will supply this software to someone not named BMW, Ford, Audi, ...

Answer (score 9):

It's probably a [Renesas R7F7016114AFD](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/renesas-electronics-corporation/R7F7016114AFD-C-BA3/16591019). They use this marking style for the RH850 series, according to [this site](https://abrites.com/blog/decoding-the-renesas-rh850-v850-part-numbers-enigma).

> You can get more information on the matter by following this link: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/gde/rh850-family-product-part-number-guide?r=487781
>
> In the case of the RH850 most of the time you will come across RH850s on the MCUs you will see no more than four digits printed. The example we can use to show you is the VDO Virtual Cockpit. This outstanding example of engineering uses R7F701401 processor, but on the processor, you can only see 1401 printed as pictured below instead of the full name of the processor:
>
> [image]

(Source: [abrites.com](https://abrites.com/blog/decoding-the-renesas-rh850-v850-part-numbers-enigma))